# Servlet 3.0: where is @WebServletContextListener?

Tags: java, servlets, annotations, servlet-3.0

I am trying to follow a Servlet 3.0 [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2009/jw-02-servlet3.html?page=2) which refers to `@WebServletContextListener`. However, I cannot find such an annotation in my `javaee-web-api-6.0.jar` dependency (I am using maven).

So, where is `@WebServletContextListener`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The annotation is called [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html). And you still have to implement [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

Comment: I was just doing more reading and came to the same conclusion. Thanks.

Comment: Actually `@WebServletContextListener` is mentioned on the official Oracle's tutorials, written by [Shing Wai Chan](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)(Author of JSR specifications)